# How to clear a particular XSLT cache using Sitecore API?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I would like to clear cache for a XSLT using Sitecore API's. Is there any way i could do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to clear the cache from the API for a specific website.
Use this code to clear the xsl cache for a specific website.

```
SiteContext mySite = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("mywebsite");
XslCache xslCache = CacheManager.GetXslCache(mySite);
xslCache.Clear();
```

Keep in mind that if you have a environment with a CMS-server and (multiple) frontendservers, clearing the cache this way only clears the cache on the particular server and not all servers.

Comment: Hi martijn, thaks for the reply. is there any way i can clear a particular xsl..?

Comment: I think publishing that xslt would be one of the solutions i guesss... though it sounds little crazy and weird.